# Python Tkinter: AttributeError: Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter. I am trying to create a GUI that has two spinboxes and two checkboxes whose values will be printed when a user clicks a particular button ("Start"). Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image

#create TK frame
root = Tk()
#identify the dimensions of the TK frame
root.geometry("360x150")
#title the TK frame
root.title("Literature Online API")

#create a function that will return the filepath for a file provided by the user
def selectfile():
    user_defined_filepath['filename'] = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text","*.txt")]) # user_defined_filepath['filename'] may now be accessed in the global scope.

#create a function that will allow the "start" button to begin further processes
def startapi(event = "<Button>"):
    print windowlengthspinbox.get()
    print slideintervalspinbox.get()
    print fuzzyspellingbutton.get()
    print lemmatizedsearchbutton.get()

#create variables for the checkbuttons -- default = 0, checked = 1
fuzzyspellingvariable = IntVar()
lemmatizedsearchvariable = IntVar()

#create a caption that will appear as the first line of the grid
firstlinelabel = Label(root, text = "Please select any desired search options:")
firstlinelabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a button that allows users to employ Literature Online's fuzzy spelling feature. Add the object.grid() method on new line because appending .grid() to the line in which one defines object causes Python to give the object attribute "NoneType." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/python-tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get
fuzzyspellingbutton = Checkbutton(root, text="Fuzzy Spelling", variable=fuzzyspellingvariable)
fuzzyspellingbutton.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a button that allows users to employ Literature Online's lemmatized search feature
lemmatizedsearchbutton = Checkbutton(root, text="Lemmatized Search", variable=lemmatizedsearchvariable)
lemmatizedsearchbutton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a spinbox that allows users to identify desired window length
windowlengthspinbox = Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=10)
windowlengthspinbox.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
windowlengthspinboxlabel = Label(root, text = "Please select window size")
windowlengthspinboxlabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a spinbox that allows users to identify desired window length
slideintervalspinbox = Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=10)
slideintervalspinbox.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)
slideintervalspinboxlabel =  Label(root, text = "Please select window slide interval")
slideintervalspinboxlabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a button that allows users to find a file for analysis    
selectfilebutton = Button(root,text="Select File",command=selectfile)
selectfilebutton.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

#create a start button that allows users to submit selected parameters and file
startbutton = Button(root, text="Start", command = startapi, width = 8)
startbutton.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = E)
startbutton.bind("<Button>", startapi)
#startbutton.focus()

#instantiate the Tk window
root.mainloop()
```

When I click the "Start" button, the GUI prints the values of the spinboxes, then tells me that Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'get':

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "groundupgui.py", line 20, in startapi
    print fuzzyspellingbutton.get()
AttributeError: Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'get'
```

Does anyone know how I can print the values of the checkboxes? I would be grateful for any suggestions or insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the state of the Checkbutton use the `fuzzyspellingvariable` that you've attached to the Checkbutton:

```
fuzzyspellingvariable.get()
```

---

By the way, since the checkbutton only has two states, you could use a BooleanVar instead of an IntVar here:

```
fuzzyspellingvariable = BooleanVar()
```

Comment: what if i dont want to create or assign new variable to checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it. You need to perform the .get() method on the variable, not the button:

```
print fuzzyspellingvariable.get()
print lemmatizedsearchvariable.get()
```